# how to find time using python?

Tags: python, function, time

i want to run my function and then I want to find now's time using python.

then lets say after 2 hours my function should run again.

what should i do?

Comment: "after 2 hours my function should run again"?  Are you asking how to use the built-in `cron` or `at`?  If so, what operating system are you using?

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways of finding the time in Python:

```
import time
print time.time() # unix timestamp, seconds from 1970

import datetime
print datetime.datetime.now()

time.sleep(7200) # sleep for 2 hours
```

Answer (score 2):

to determine current time, you can use pythons [datetime module](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html)

```
from datetime import datetime
print datetime.datetime.now();
```

To run script every two hours - this is a job to crontab deamon. This is a special process in UNIX systems that executed commands in periods of time.

Read about setting up cron jobs here: http://blog.dreamhosters.com/kbase/index.cgi?area=2506

Comment: This doesn't work. Either `import datetime` or `print datetime.now()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
import datetime
import time

def func():
    # your function
    pass


while True:
    func() # call you function
    print datetime.datetime.now() # print current datetime
    time.sleep(2*60*60) # sleep for 2 hours
```

However, a better way for a scheduled operation would be to use `cron`, as @Silver Light suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Is your process going to be running for hours at a time and doing other things? If so you can mark the time like so:

```
from time import time

start_time = time()   # current time expressed as seconds since 1/1/1970

...

now = time()
if (now - start_time) >= (2 * 60 * 60):   # number of seconds in 2 hours
  do_function()
```

Otherwise, if it will not need to do anything for 2 hours, you can do:

```
from time import sleep

quit_condition = False

if not quit_condition:
  sleep(2 * 60 * 60)     # control will not return to this thread for 2 hours
  quit_condition = do_function()
```

In the second scenario, presumably your function will indicate whether or not the main loop can be exited.